# CsvWriter, CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I'm using CsvHelper (great package thanks Josh) and having problems with the constructor with .Net Core when using CultureInfo.

Josh's example has something like this... 
(from https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-class-objects)

```
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
   using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
   {
      csv.WriteRecords(records);
   }
```

However, that gives me, CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' to 'CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration'

so, I need to do this instead

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer: writer  ))
   {
      csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ; 
      csv.WriteRecords(records);
   }
```

Is Josh's example wrong or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: i think your code is correct. Maybe that example is old.

Comment: What version of CsvHelper are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh's example works with the current CsvHelper, Version 13.0.0

```cs
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
   csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

Before Version 13.0.0, your example works.

```cs
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
   csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; 
   csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

Comment: Argh, that explains it.  I'm using 12.1.2